# UDP client periodic sendto() delay in C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I am developing a UDP client in C in Linux with glibc 2.23. My application sends small packets (11 bytes) in a loop with a rate of 20,000 packets/sec.

To ensure that the client met its promised send rate, I instrumented my application to measure UDP send timings when I saw a strange behavior. The time it takes to send a packet (a call to `sendto()` function) is "usually" around 13 usec.

But approximately every 30 msec, there is a call which takes around 50 usec and approximately every 1500 ms, there is a call which takes 160 usec. The numbers are approximate and are average of a long 1 minute run.

The graph below shows the delay values for 5 second run of the application.
[image: sendto() call delay as a function of runtime]

Here are the things that I tried:

- Using affinity to pin my application to a core to avoid context switch
- Changing the UDP send/receive buffer size from 100K to 1G (smaller buffer sizes slightly reduces the amount of delay but not the frequency)
- Changing form IPV4 to IPV6 (no difference)

Also tried:

- Disabled `arp` (address resolution protocol)
- Ran the test while the server and client were at the same machine as well as two different machines (connected via a switch), no difference in the results
- switched between the 10G and 1G NICs, no difference in the results
- Ran client and server on two docker instances on the same machine connected via a virtual bridge, no difference in the results.

I was wondering if anyone experienced such behavior?

I appreciate any suggestion about the cause or solution to avoid the costly calls?

Comment: Yes, and I set PORT_REUSE option to 0 to be able to track the response from the server. so each send involves a call to socket(), bind() and sendto() functions. The times shown in the graph is only for sendto() call. bind() and socket calls usually takes around 7 usec.

Comment: Why? Why not use the same socket for the life of the application?

Comment: That's because of the nature of the application, the application should be able to measure the round trip time for each packet. Initially i was reusing the ports but it caused conflict for the measurements. When the response to two requests sent from the same port were arriving out of order, my application didn`t have a mechanism to figure out which response was for which request.

Comment: Can you show the C code as to what your application send loop looks like?

Comment: To rule out changing ports being an issue, can you adjust your protocol to not need distinct ports?

Comment: This sounds like normal behavior for a non-real-time thread... every so often, some part of the UDP transmission path gets held off as the system attends to some other task instead.  If you need hard real-time performance guarantees, you'll need to use a hard-real-time thread (e.g. via Xenomai or similar)

Comment: Thanks @jxh, I ran a test with port reuse and the result didn`t change. Still the same pattern for the delays.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner. Even with the CPU affinity the system switches into other tasks? I also set the flag for the sendto() function to be non-blocking. But  these results confirm that it is occasionally blocking!

Comment: Is it blocking, or is it just not returning as quickly as usual, e.g. because the thread has been pre-empted by some other activity?  (Btw if you aren't already calling sched_setscheduler() to make your thread real-time-ish, you might want to try that; it might help keep your thread on the CPU more reliably.  It's only "soft real-time" though, so you still might see holdoffs occasionally)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You were right, the problem is related to scheduling not the UDP sendto(). I used the sched_setscheduler(), the maximum delay didn`t change much but the pattern we see in the above graph is gone and replace by an irregular shape. I probably need to rephrase the question and ask it with modified tags but I am still curious when I use CPU affinity and no other process is running on this core, and i know that there is no context switch for my process, what causes those delays? are the system calls run on other CPUs? what else is running during delay time?

Comment: Are you sure no other process is running on the core?  AFAIK pinning a process keeps that process on the core, but doesn't necessarily keep other processes off of the core.  Anyway, I'm not expert enough on the subject to give details, but generally unless the scheduler was designed very carefully from the ground up to be hard-real-time, there are various things that can cause holdoffs; e.g. servicing an interrupt, or waiting for a mutex that is locked by another part of the kernel.

Comment: @RSH2000 Did you manage to solve this issue? I am facing the exact same problem.