# Periodic lag when sending/receiving Udp from Android

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp, wifi

I have an Android app that streams Audio to Desktop clients via UDP on a local network. The phone is connected via Wifi, the clients either via Wifi or wired.

Unfortunately I experience periodic delays. I am aware that I cannot rely on Wifi being low latency, but my lags come like a clockwork, which is suspicious. If I set my sample rate to 48000 on a mono channel and 16 Bit Depth (=96000 bytes per second) and set the packet length to 384 bytes (~4ms), I experience a larger lag (~170ms) every 1024 packets (4.096 seconds). The smaller lags are less regular:

```
after 293 packets we got a delay of 35 ms
after 309 packets we got a delay of 38 ms
after 311 packets we got a delay of 35 ms
after 108 packets we got a delay of 183 ms
after 202 packets we got a delay of 34 ms
after 310 packets we got a delay of 34 ms
after 309 packets we got a delay of 38 ms
after 180 packets we got a delay of 42 ms
after 26 packets we got a delay of 171 ms
after 104 packets we got a delay of 38 ms
after 311 packets we got a delay of 34 ms
after 310 packets we got a delay of 34 ms
after 299 packets we got a delay of 171 ms
after 200 packets we got a delay of 43 ms
after 85 packets we got a delay of 23 ms
after 35 packets we got a delay of 38 ms
after 311 packets we got a delay of 35 ms
after 309 packets we got a delay of 36 ms
after 10 packets we got a delay of 46 ms
after 74 packets we got a delay of 170 ms
after 176 packets we got a delay of 44 ms
after 50 packets we got a delay of 38 ms
after 310 packets we got a delay of 39 ms
after 311 packets we got a delay of 35 ms
after 177 packets we got a delay of 172 ms
after 133 packets we got a delay of 34 ms
after 310 packets we got a delay of 35 ms
after 310 packets we got a delay of 35 ms
after 271 packets we got a delay of 189 ms
```

If I filter for lags >50ms, I get something like this

```
after 1024 packets we got a delay of 173 ms
after 1020 packets we got a delay of 188 ms
after 1028 packets we got a delay of 171 ms
after 1024 packets we got a delay of 171 ms
after 1024 packets we got a delay of 170 ms
after 1024 packets we got a delay of 170 ms
after 1024 packets we got a delay of 170 ms
```

Changing the packet size from 384 bytes to 1024 bytes means the lags come every 384 packets instead of every 1024 packets. So I thought it has to do with the total bytes sent (384 * 1024), but that's incorrect, because if I half the throughput via the sample rate and leave the packet size the same, it takes half as many packets for the lag to spike. *It has to do with time.*

**What I tried**

On the sending side, the implementation does not matter much, which is why I won't bother with code here. I tried plain Datagram Sockets in Kotlin. Now I am doing a native approach, where I read audio with the Oboe library and send the packets with `sendto`. There is also an option to use a callback via the Oboe library, which apparently uses a high priority thread. All three methods result in the same lag. I also tried changing thread priorities myself, as well as pinning the thread to a core. The app *seems* to send the packets on time if I look at the logs, but I am not sure if the data is not stuck in the kernel somewhere (I really don't know enough about this).

On the receiving side, the OS does not matter, both Linux and Windows (using Winsock) show the same lag. Changing thread affinity or setting the priority to real-time does not change anything. Having a receiver on Wifi or on a wired connection makes no difference. The phone is always on Wifi.

**Facts**

The larger lags come every 4.096 seconds, regardless of the sending frequency or packet size. The target OS also does not matter. Which leads me to believe it has to do with some Android scheduling problem. However, I have not found many people facing the same problem, which is weird since Android is so popular. I only found a lonely guy with a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969421/udp-client-periodic-sendto-delay-in-c-in-linux) issue, but the suggestions there did not help me.

Comment: Are you using a modem-router? The problem may come from a service running on the router. Have you tried replacing it with a router that is not a modem?

Answer (score 1):

On Android, you can enable the [Wi-Fi Low-Latency Mode](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-low-latency).

**OnResume**

```
val wifiManager = this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as android.net.wifi.WifiManager
val wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY else android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, null)
wifiLock.acquire()
```

**OnPause**

```
wifiLock.release()
```

This should fix your lag problem.